What does this 'i' mark indicate in Global offensive?
I am curious to know what the pop-up 'i' mark indicates. It appears sometimes and in certain places and later disappears. Are they indicating something, or do they appear because of some ping or latency issue?


You and your teammates can ping/mark on any spot (by default using the middle mouse button).
This will appear, as you said, briefly on every teammate's screen. In this case, you could say someone saw an enemy left of the door.
You can also see your own marking/ping.
If the middle mouse button doesn't work, check the settings:
Settings → Keyboard/mouse → Communication → "Player ping"
A short tutorial on YouTube:




Welcome to Arqade! Please keep in mind that it is always better to include the essential parts of the answer and provide the link only for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

The link was for provided for additional info, will remove it then

It's fine to include the link, just not have visiting it be the only way to answer the question :)
